# How to deal with the large space occupied by the wal file in the datanode of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question for Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.1, what is signifance of the concept of pre-writing log? The `wal` file in the datanode of my IoTDB server now takes up a lot of space, 500 gigabytes. The space settings of this single node were previously modified due to synchronization issues. How can I now clean it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade to the newest 1.2.2. version of Apache IoTDB. This may be a bug for the previous versions, so you can see if upgrading version will solve your problem.